# Cpanel update failed

Tags: cpanel, centos6

```
[2015-11-25 18:00:55 +0000]   Retrieving and staging /cpanelsync/11.52.1.2/binaries/linux-c6-x86_64/uapi.xz
[2015-11-25 18:00:55 +0000]   Retrying download of /cpanelsync/11.52.1.2/binaries/linux-c6-x86_64/uapi.xz (attempt 2/5): Failed to decompress XZ data from '/usr/local/cpanel/uapi-cpanelsync' at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 35459, <$__ANONIO__> line 198.
[2015-11-25 18:00:55 +0000]   Retrying download of /cpanelsync/11.52.1.2/binaries/linux-c6-x86_64/uapi.xz (attempt 3/5): Failed to decompress XZ data from '/usr/local/cpanel/uapi-cpanelsync' at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 35459, <$__ANONIO__> line 396.
[2015-11-25 18:00:56 +0000]   Retrying download of /cpanelsync/11.52.1.2/binaries/linux-c6-x86_64/uapi.xz (attempt 4/5): Failed to decompress XZ data from '/usr/local/cpanel/uapi-cpanelsync' at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 35459, <$__ANONIO__> line 594.
[2015-11-25 18:00:56 +0000]   Retrying download of /cpanelsync/11.52.1.2/binaries/linux-c6-x86_64/uapi.xz (attempt 5/5): Failed to decompress XZ data from '/usr/local/cpanel/uapi-cpanelsync' at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 35459, <$__ANONIO__> line 792.
[2015-11-25 18:00:56 +0000]   The Administrator will be notified to review this output when this script completes
[2015-11-25 18:00:56 +0000] E Unable to stage file from /binaries/linux-c6-x86_64/uapi => /usr/local/cpanel/uapi: Failed to decompress XZ data from '/usr/local/cpanel/uapi-cpanelsync' at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 35459, <$__ANONIO__> line 990.
[2015-11-25 18:00:56 +0000]   The Administrator will be notified to review this output when this script completes
[2015-11-25 18:00:57 +0000] E Sync child 8776 exited with signal: 9 and code: 0
[2015-11-25 18:00:57 +0000]   The Administrator will be notified to review this output when this script completes
[2015-11-25 18:00:57 +0000] E Failed to deserialize staged_files from: /var/tmp/7655.ANEL_SCRIPTS_UPDATENOW_STATIC_CPANELSYNC__.cW8NPqfHacJgZWGL.tmp because of an error: malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 25113.
[2015-11-25 18:00:57 +0000]   The Administrator will be notified to review this output when this script completes
[2015-11-25 18:00:57 +0000] ***** FATAL: Failed to stage “cpanel changes” because of an error: Failed to deserialize staged_files from: /var/tmp/7655.ANEL_SCRIPTS_UPDATENOW_STATIC_CPANELSYNC__.cW8NPqfHacJgZWGL.tmp because of an error: malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow.static-cpanelsync line 25113.
[2015-11-25 18:00:57 +0000]   The Administrator will be notified to review    this output when this script completes
 => Log closed Wed Nov 25 18:00:57 2015
[2015-11-25 18:01:04 +0000]   17% complete
[2015-11-25 18:01:04 +0000] E Running `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/updatenow --upcp --log=/var/cpanel/updatelogs/update.1448473646.log --force` failed, exited with code 12 (signal = 0)
=> Log closed Wed Nov 25 18:01:21 2015
```

I have fixed a few dependencies and I keep getting this error. I cant seem to fix update now but im running upcp via ssh and fails there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to upadte cPanel with the following command and let us know if the issue persists?

```
/scripts/upcp --force
```